# Logstash CSV filter - ignore new line char within double quotes

Tags: csv, filter, logstash, multiline

While using logstash filter for csv, it treats every new line character as line break and treat next characters in next line even if these are within double quotes.CSV file have some columns which contain multiple lines of text within double quotes. Can logstash somehow ignore new line character within double quotes? my config is as follows.

```
input {
    s3 {

          bucket => "abcbucket"
          region => "eu-west-1"
          type => "spa"
          prefix => "input/2017/SPA"
          aws_credentials_file => "/Users/abc/project/def/config/s3-credentials.yaml"
          sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
csv {
    columns => ["column1", "column2", "column3","column4"]
    separator => ","
    convert => { 
      "column1" => "integer" 
      "column2" => "integer"   
  }
}
}
output {
elasticsearch
    {
            hosts => ["abc.def.com:80"]
            index => "abc-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

    }
}
```

column 3 have multiple lines of text most of the times. really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is best solved at the source. In your config, you should configure your `s3 {}` section with the multiline codec. I'm *guessing* that 'lines' that are actually continued column3's don't start with a quote character. If that's the case, it should be pretty straight forward to configure multiline to consider lines that don't start with a quote to be long to the previous line.